# wp-config.php is configured but database makes no connection

Tags: php, wordpress, restore

I am trying to repare my wordpress website. I installed XAMPP and made a database, but I get install.php when I want to acces my website. I tried a few things:

- rename DB_NAME, DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD to match the database in wp-config.php
- created a database with the information which was allready in wp-confif.php
- I tried to repair the website using define(‘WP_ALLOW_REPAIR’, true);. I got errors where the database was unable to find a few tables.

I really would like to make my website work again so I can continue on my project.

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: can you please share database error ?

Comment: Have you granted the right permissions to the DB user?

Comment: restoring requires you to import the old db into the new db and use wpcli to rename the old domain, you haven't mentioned you done that, simply changing connection details wont bring in your old data, instead once connected it would throw you to a install page which is not what you want if you want to restore